# triggering mouseover event via cursor key menu navigation

Tags: jquery, events, navigation, svg, onmouseover

Bit of a complex scenario here.

I have an embeded SVG graphic that will be altered by changes made to the parent HTML document.
I have a text box and as you type a search into it, it will populate an ajax UL list.
Navigation can be either selected via mouse or cursor key up and down.
Selecting an item via return or mouseclick.

All these work well.  I have added a method when a menu item is hovered over with the mouse, it will display the desired result in the SVG document.

I am doing this via a onmouseover event added to the li when it is generated in the PHP ajax call.

```
?><li class="<?=searchClass?>" onClick="win.hidePopup(); document.getElementById('<?=$field?>').value = '<?=$line->textName?>';"  onMouseOver="svgCreateCircle(<?=$x?>,<?=$y?>,'red','<?=$line->textName?>');"><?=$img?><?=$line->textName?></li>
<?
```

The onmouseover has to be added at this point as it is from here that I am passing parameters (x,y,text, colour) to the SVG document so it knows what to place and where so I can't use the jquery method to dynamically attach a mouseover event.

The issue I have is getting the keyboard navigation to do the same thing as the mouse navigation.  moving the mouse over the li element will display perfectly the result in the graphic, but navigating with cursor keys does not.  I get all the background changes etc simulating a mouseover but not the mouseover event it's self.  Attempting to triger the event does nothing either.

I have used :

```
$("ul#itemSearchlist li").eq(menuitem).mouseover();
$("ul#itemSearchlist li").eq(menuitem).trigger('mouseenter');
$("ul#itemSearchlist li").eq(menuitem).trigger('hover');
```

but none of those work

Comment: Three quick questions. 1: what version of jQuery are you using? 2: does the mouse over work when you normally mouseover it. 3: have you tried `.trigger('mouseover')`?

Comment: 1: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js
2: Yes.  the real mouse over works perfectly
3: tried it, didn't work

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't have 1.4.2 but it had 1.4.4 and i'm guessing there isn't any major changes between them. http://jsfiddle.net/LbkYv/2/ and it seems to work. Maybe there is an error in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It may be necessary to abstract this out so that you are no longer relying on the mouseover event to keep track of changes in the selection state, and instead keep track of the selection state yourself in JavaScript. The idea is that you would keep track of which item is selected (the state), and register event handlers to update the state. So, on the mouseover event, you update the mouseover event target, and execute the desired action (creating the circle). In the case of keyboard events, you would be able to retrieve the previous and next list items via DOM, on up keypress and down keypress, respectively. After updating the state to the previous or next list item, you would be able to again perform the desired action of creating the circle based on the updated selection state.

Comment: The tracking state of the list is already tracked.  The menu navigation is a shared resourced used by many different areas.

I use the following to track the current selected state : 

    if($('ul#itemSearchList li.itemHover').size() == 0)
    {
        currentSelection = -1; 
    }

the mouseover is not used to track the currently selected menu, but to bring about the desired action

Comment: So, given that you may not be able to reliably trigger DOM events using script, you should probably make the mouseover event and keypress event delegate to the same function, such that that function uses the tracked state to perform the desired action. That way, you don't need to rely on emulating a mouseover event upon receiving a keypress event, which may be unreliable.